# How to run elevated shell from within console2 (Windows 8.1)? Possible?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, shell, console2, elevated

I come from Linux, and for days I have been pulling my hair out trying to run an elevated shell (powershell, ipython interpreter, and bash) from within Console2. However, it always pops open a new cmd.exe window, that is not what I want, I want to drop down into the elevated shell from the same tab in the same window that I am in. How can I accomplish this?

I just installed sudowin, and it is sort of what I want, but it just opens a new cmd.exe window as I stated. I can't run `sudo .\Console.exe` though, it just says `Command not allowed` without prompting for my password, I also can not run `Console.exe` as administrator by right clicking, it just drops privileges right away.

Perhaps I am being spoiled, but the cmd.exe terminal emulator is ugly, and I really want to use Console2 (its the prettiest I have found), and to drop into an elevated shell when I need to.

I can't imagine trying to do administrative work remotely, what a nightmare having to call and be like "Did an admin cmd prompt pop up on your end?". So much work has gone into Windows, and I respect that, but sheesh, talk about overlooking the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 3rd party tool called [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to get additional features like [elevation](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/elevate.html).

```
nircmd elevate Console.exe
```

Put the Nircmd.exe into the Windows directory so that you can run it from all places.